# Oracle's imp.exe problems over tunneled connection

Tags: sql, oracle, import, ora-12514

We have an Oracle server running in a remote server which only has an SSH connection and we need to run data import process against that.

I tried different SSH tunnel combinations:

- 127.0.0.1:1521
- 127.0.0.1:1522
- 127.0.0.1:11111
- 127.0.0.107:1522
- 127.0.0.107:11111

But none of them work with imp.exe. Intresting thing that all those combinations works just fine with SQL Developer and [Scriptella](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/) scripts that use JDBC. The following error is shown in standard error output:

```
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 12514 encountered
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

And the following appears in the sqlnet.log:

```
***********************************************************************
Fatal NI connect error 12514, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=tktdb1)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\imp.exe)(HOST=...)(USER=...)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=11111)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 07-MAR-2011 10:53:26
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564
    TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asume that the connect strings are correct. If they are: does you database happen to be in restricted mode? In that case, the service it supports are not available for connections. If that is the case, try connecting with a tns alias using SID=xxx

I fail to see what ssh has for impact here. The database connection is working. ssh only plays a role if you need to tunnel your database connection through ssh. If your normal sql client can connect without this, imp can do the same. Normally ssh is only used to connect to the server, which is not needed in your case.

I hope this helps,
Ronald.

Comment: You are correct: when in SQL Developer I changed to connecting with SERVICE NAME instead of SID, it failed with the same exception as imp. After talking to my database administrator it appeared that SERVICE NAME and SID for database have different values. After using configured SERVICE NAME with the imp it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Do you know if imp can be configured to use SID instead of SERVICE NAME?

Comment: yes, I know .. ;-) and yes we can. Normally you can use the contents of the tns alias definition as connect string to an Oracle database. It could be smarter to create a tns alias that connects based on the ORACLE_SID. Using the correct definition is better than using the ORACLE_SID because the ORACLE_SID is very lowlevel and prevents you from using an other instance incase you happen to be on a RAC database. Service_name is better to use but the administration must be in control.